# Error 500 when calling payment creation via REST API

Tags: rest, paypal

I trying the new Paypal REST API and want integrate it in sandbox mode into a simple site just to see is it possible to implement one of the following payment flows:

### Flow1

1) user fills the payment form, including credit card information
2) user clicks Buy
3) browser stores credit card information in paypal vault via REST API for credit cards (card id used later).
4) browser creates payment for the purchase via REST API call.
5) browser calls app server to ensure that purchase is going on.
5) browser redirects user to url provided by paypal.
6) when user consent/approval received at paypal website, and site redirected back to welcome page,
7) under the hood the IPN callback receives the conformation of payment and marks purchase as paid
8) user obtains access to the service app provides

### Flow 2

1) user fills the payment form, including credit card information
2) user clicks Buy
4) browser creates payment for the purchase via REST API call.
5) browser calls app server to ensure that purchase is going on.
5) browser redirects user to url provided by paypal.
6) when user consent/approval received at paypal website, and site redirected back to welcome page,
7) under the hood the IPN callback receives the conformation of payment and marks purchase as paid and uses a bit more pf purchase details like credit card type and last 4 digits to add this info to my purchase object.
8) user obtains the access to services the application provides
8) user obtains access to the service app provides

### Reasons to implement all this in such way

Mostly I going this path because i don't want deal with  all this PCI compliance, and hones;ty i don't care where customers of my app live, which exactly card numbers they used, or when the card expire, since i don't want use automated subscription like payment, i want use different model:
user gets some pats of service for free, but to use rest of service, user buys time intervals of improved access (e. g. X months or 1 year).
This is what i trying to implement without storing credit cards information or storing as less as possible (paypal credit card id is enough i guess).

### Question

Can i implement all this with Paypal REST API?

What i trying to do:

```
PaypalAdapter.prototype.sendCreditCardPayment = function (amount, description, creditCard, success, failure) {
    var ccNumberResult = this.impl.validator.validateCardNumber(creditCard.number);
    if (!ccNumberResult.success) {
        return this.impl.$q.reject(ccNumberResult);
    }

    var cardInfo = {
        number: ccNumberResult.number,
        type: ccNumberResult.type,
        expire_month: creditCard.expireMonth,
        expire_year: String(creditCard.expireYear),
        cvv2: creditCard.securityCode,
        first_name: creditCard.firstName,
        last_name: creditCard.lastName
    };

    var self = this;
    var defer = self.impl.$q.defer();
    this.impl.storeCardAPI(cardInfo,
        function cardTokenCreated(cardTokenReply) {
            var paymentSettings = {
                intent: self.PaymentIntents.Sale,
                redirect_urls: {
                    return_url: self.urls.returnUrl,
                    cancel_url: self.urls.cancelUrl
                },
                payer: {
                    payment_method: self.PayMethods.CreditCard,
                    funding_instruments: [
                        {
                            credit_card_token: {
                                credit_card_id: cardTokenReply.id
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            total: String(amount.toFixed(2)),
                            currency: self.currencyCode
                        },
                        description: description
                    }
                ]
            };
            self.impl.createPaymentAPI(paymentSettings, function paymentCreated(payment) {
                defer.resolve(payment);
            }, function failedToCreatePayment(pcErr) {
                defer.reject(pcErr);
            });
        },
        function failedToStoreCard(ctErr) {
            defer.reject(ctErr);
        });
    return defer.promise.then(success, failure);
};
```

To keep context more clean, here some more pieces of code:

```
var defaultHeaders = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + securityContext.tokens.paypal.access_token,
        Accept: 'application/json'
    };

    var createPaymentResource = $resource(securityContext.configuration.paypal.endPoint + 'payments/payment', {}, {
        sendPayment : {
            method:'POST',
            headers: defaultHeaders
        }
    });
    var saveCreditCardResource = $resource(securityContext.configuration.paypal.endPoint + "vault/credit-cards", {}, {
        storeCreditCard: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: defaultHeaders
        }
    });

    function storeCardFunc(cardInfo, success, failure) {
        return saveCreditCardResource.storeCreditCard(null, cardInfo, success, failure);
    }

    function createPaymentFunc(paymentInformation, success, failure) {
        return createPaymentResource.sendPayment(null, paymentInformation, success, failure);
    }

    var adapter = new PaypalAdapter($q, securityContext, creditCardValidator, storeCardFunc, createPaymentFunc);
    return adapter;
```

### Current "Results"

What i getting:
1) I can store credit card into vault via REST API.
2) i getting error 500 on try to create payment whether i use plain credit card properties to fill credit card funding instrument or try to use credit card token instead.

What i'm doing wrong?

### Update

My mistake is a sort of logical with a lack of knowledge.
1) The direct credit cards payments (weather user approves them manually (with intent 'order' and payment_method = 'credit_card'), or not ('sale' intent and payment method 'credit_card') are not available for my country (Republic of Georgia). This is a single reason for the error i see.
Discovered this via Paypal account pages at developer.paypal.com website... It is a frustrating thing. Especially with all this too cryptic "internal server error". I t would be VERY helpful if Paypal would provide at least an informative message "Requested feature not available for your account" with info link to that page with available/enabled features.
Also documentation s a bit broken - some fields like first_name or last_name of payer object of order/payment request are NOT expected by the /payments/payment endpoint...

Comment: Could you show a sample of the resulting request? With Firebug, you see that in the console. That would help make sure the output is as expected by PayPal.

Comment: Will mae an update, hold on...

Comment: I have to agree that the documentations are not top notch!